# Linkedin API integration with phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am getting request token and oauth verification also
I have getting url like for accessToken but it is not valid url and getting error

(https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken?oauth_consumer_key=bszdp1xlaa4o&oauth_nonce=mSwft&oauth_signature=li7zoL3Jw3sdg6H42iwUronjcHg%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1369053418&oauth_token=fe69dc1f-4cc8-4baa-89d6-e5087e119fb2&oauth_verifier=30000)

My question is: Why am I not getting right accesstoken url, what am  I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to copy what [these guys](https://github.com/jor3l/phonegap-oauth) do?